# List items linked android

Tags: android, listview

Pretty much I have a listview, where if you press one button, the other is meant to change to a dark grey image. The code works fine on an individual level, but for some reason the action is replicated every 4th list item. Here is the getItemView code! (By the way I have indeed tried making the imagebuttons local!)

```
ImageButton thumbsUpButton;
ImageButton thumbsDownButton;
@Override
public View getItemView(FactListParseObject factRow, View v,
        ViewGroup parent) {

    if (v == null) {
        v = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.fact_list_row, null);
    }

    super.getItemView(factRow, v, parent);

    setTexts(v, factRow);

    thumbsUpButton = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.thumbsup);
    thumbsDownButton = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.thumbsdown);

    if (thumbsDownButton != null&& thumbsUpButton!=null) {
    thumbsUpButton.setTag(false);
    thumbsDownButton.setTag(false);

    thumbsUpButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if((boolean)thumbsUpButton.getTag()==true){

                thumbsUpButton
                        .setImageResource(R.drawable.thumbsup);
                thumbsUpButton.setTag(false);
            }
            if ((boolean)thumbsDownButton.getTag() == false) {
                // thumbsdown not currently disabled
                thumbsDownButton
                        .setImageResource(R.drawable.thumbsdowndisabled);
                thumbsDownButton.setTag(true);


            } else {
                // thumbsdown is disabled
                thumbsDownButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.thumbsdown);
                thumbsDownButton.setTag(false);

            }
        }
    });
    thumbsDownButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d("called","howmany");
            if((boolean)thumbsDownButton.getTag()==true){

                thumbsDownButton
                        .setImageResource(R.drawable.thumbsdown);
                thumbsDownButton.setTag(false);
            }
            if ((boolean)thumbsUpButton.getTag() == false) {
                // thumbsdown not currently disabled
                thumbsUpButton
                        .setImageResource(R.drawable.thumbsupdisabled);
                thumbsUpButton.setTag(true);


            } else {
                // thumbsdown is disabled
                thumbsUpButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.thumbsup);
                thumbsUpButton.setTag(false);

            }
        }
    });
    }
    return v;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the ListView recycles the view, therefore the fourth is the recycled one ...
So you have to "reset" the state (in your case the color of the button) for every item in your list (or in other words for each cell in your listview) ...

btw. the methods name is getView and not getItemView()

Here you can find an abstract base adapter class, that helps you to handle better the "lifecycle" of a listview cell:
https://github.com/sockeqwe/appkit/blob/master/adapter/src/main/java/com/hannesdorfmann/appkit/adapter/SimpleAdapter.java

The idea is that there are two key methods:

- `newView()` Here you inflate the View from layout and setup the ViewHolder pattern.
- `bindView()` Here you bind the view cell (may be a recycled or a new created one from `newView()` ) to your data object that should "fill" the cell with the desired data. So here is where you should set the color of the button ...